# Huge CPU load/poor performance php zend system written by Flash Builder data wizard

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, flash-builder, cpu

I am a self-taught AS3/Flex/AIR developer and I have built a system of touchscreen-kiosks running on AIR with remote content managment from an online Flex app.

This is the first time I have done server side stuff, so feel free to correct my question if needed.

Both the AIR apps and the Flex app connect to a mysql database for simple CRUD operations using php scripts and the Zend framework. The kiosks call the server every 30 seconds to update.

All these simple server side php scripts were auto-generated by Flash Builder's data wizard. I did the simple adjusments (gateway.php, amf_config.ini, mysqli connection parameters) and deployed everything to the client's server. This is a a shared-server type.

Now, the system works. But it works slowly. Each create/read/update/delete operation works but I think it should be a lot faster.
Also, these operations put a lot of load on the server's cpu.
According to the hosting guys, this system opens php-cgi proccesses that take up 40% of the server cpu power, and by doing so slows itself down and other sites hosted on that server.

My questions are:

First of all, is there a problem to begin with or is this performance expexted from the Zend framework?
Are the auto-generated scripts written by Flash Builder poorly written and can be optimized?
Can this kind of system stay on a shared-hosted-server? Should we move to a VPS server for better performance? 
Is it posiible that if the tables I created on the mysql database with phpmyadmin weren't optimiatlly built that it would have this kind of impact on performance?

I don't know php or mysql.
Any kind of help will be much appriciated.

Saar

Here is the script written by Flash Builder: I havn't added anything - just changed the connection parameters.

```
<?php

class KiosksService {

   var $username = "--------";
   var $password = "--------";
   var $server = "--------";
   var $port = "3306";
   var $databasename = "--------";
   var $tablename = "kiosks";

   var $connection;

   /**
    * The constructor initializes the connection to database. Everytime a request is 
    * received by Zend AMF, an instance of the service class is created and then the
    * requested method is invoked.
    */
   public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(
                          $this->server,  
                          $this->username,  
                          $this->password, 
                          $this->databasename,
                          $this->port
                       );

      $this->throwExceptionOnError($this->connection);
   }

   /**
    * Returns all the rows from the table.
    *
    * Add authroization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
    *
    * @return array
    */
   public function getAllKiosks() {

      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename");      
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      $rows = array();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->KioskID, $row->Station, $row->Branch, $row->Chain, $row->Pingdate, $row->Layout, $row->Online, $row->Clips, $row->Extra);

       while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
         $row->Pingdate = new DateTime($row->Pingdate);
         $rows[] = $row;
         $row = new stdClass();
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->KioskID, $row->Station, $row->Branch, $row->Chain, $row->Pingdate, $row->Layout, $row->Online, $row->Clips, $row->Extra);
       }

      mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
       mysqli_close($this->connection);

       return $rows;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the item corresponding to the value specified for the primary key.
    *
    * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
    *
    * 
    * @return stdClass
    */
   public function getKiosksByID($itemID) {

      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename where KioskID=?");
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $itemID);      
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->KioskID, $row->Station, $row->Branch, $row->Chain, $row->Pingdate, $row->Layout, $row->Online, $row->Clips, $row->Extra);

      if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
         $row->Pingdate = new DateTime($row->Pingdate);
         return $row;
      } else {
         return null;
      }
   }

   /**
    * Returns the item corresponding to the value specified for the primary key.
    *
    * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
    *
    * 
    * @return stdClass
    */
   public function createKiosks($item) {

      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "INSERT INTO $this->tablename (Station, Branch, Chain, Pingdate, Layout, Online, Clips, Extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssisi', $item->Station, $item->Branch, $item->Chain, $item->Pingdate->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), $item->Layout, $item->Online, $item->Clips, $item->Extra);
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);      
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      $autoid = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);

      mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);      
      mysqli_close($this->connection);

      return $autoid;
   }

   /**
    * Updates the passed item in the table.
    *
    * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
    *
    * @param stdClass $item
    * @return void
    */
   public function updateKiosks($item) {

      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "UPDATE $this->tablename SET Station=?, Branch=?, Chain=?, Pingdate=?, Layout=?, Online=?, Clips=?, Extra=? WHERE KioskID=?");      
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssisii', $item->Station, $item->Branch, $item->Chain, $item->Pingdate->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), $item->Layout, $item->Online, $item->Clips, $item->Extra, $item->KioskID);      
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);      
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);      
      mysqli_close($this->connection);
   }

   /**
    * Deletes the item corresponding to the passed primary key value from 
    * the table.
    *
    * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
    *
    * 
    * @return void
    */
   public function deleteKiosks($itemID) {

      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "DELETE FROM $this->tablename WHERE KioskID = ?");
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $itemID);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);      
      mysqli_close($this->connection);
   }


   /**
    * Returns the number of rows in the table.
    *
    * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
    *
    * 
    */
   public function count() {
      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM $this->tablename");
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $rec_count);
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
      mysqli_close($this->connection);

      return $rec_count;
   }


   /**
    * Returns $numItems rows starting from the $startIndex row from the 
    * table.
    *
    * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
    *
    * 
    * 
    * @return array
    */
   public function getKiosks_paged($startIndex, $numItems) {

      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename LIMIT ?, ?");
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $startIndex, $numItems);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      $rows = array();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->KioskID, $row->Station, $row->Branch, $row->Chain, $row->Pingdate, $row->Layout, $row->Online, $row->Clips, $row->Extra);

       while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
         $row->Pingdate = new DateTime($row->Pingdate);
         $rows[] = $row;
         $row = new stdClass();
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->KioskID, $row->Station, $row->Branch, $row->Chain, $row->Pingdate, $row->Layout, $row->Online, $row->Clips, $row->Extra);
       }

      mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);      
      mysqli_close($this->connection);

      return $rows;
   }


   /**
    * Utility function to throw an exception if an error occurs 
    * while running a mysql command.
    */
   private function throwExceptionOnError($link = null) {
      if($link == null) {
         $link = $this->connection;
      }
      if(mysqli_error($link)) {
         $msg = mysqli_errno($link) . ": " . mysqli_error($link);
         throw new Exception('MySQL Error - '. $msg);
      }      
   }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While performance can be a bit of a problem with the Zend framework, *there's no zend framework code* in your example.

> this system opens 6 php-cgi proccesses

For each operation? That seems unlikely. It would be helpful if you provided a sample of the access log showing a typical transaction along with the evidence they provided to support this assertion.

Running php via cgi is a *really bad idea* if you're in the slightest bit concerned about performance (or how hot your server room is). Using mod_php or php-fpm or even php via fcgi along with an opcode cache will reduce execution time by more than 75%.

Looking at the code, there's nothing here obviously bad - except for getKiosks_paged - doing row range selections without an explicit ORDER BY is very sloppy.

> Each create/read/update/delete operation works but I think it should be a lot faster

How fast is it? How long is the request on the websrver, what queries does it execute? How long do they take? What is the structure of your database? What does the explain plan for your queries look like?

Comment: thank you symcbean. you are right - those 6 processes are for 6 operations, i will change the question. As i said i know no php - does changing from cgi to mod_php or pfp-fpm (whatever all that means) involve changing the php script only or more server side configurations?

Comment: Also, a query like getAllKiosks in the attached script, which accesses a mysql table with about 8 fields and only 10 or so items in it takes something like 8 seconds from when the "update" button in the flex app is clicked till the corrisponding datagrid refreshes

Comment: and also, where is the Zend code? Zend is automatically installed by the Flash Builder (again, all server side is generated by FB automatically). Is the code in the gateway.php and amf_config.ini files? Are these not just files directing the flex service call to the correct php scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the Zend framework, because I never used it.

CGI will always be slower than Fast CGI or, better yet, mod_php or something similar. When you use CGI, every time an interpreter is started and after the script completes everything is torn down.

When you use Fast CGI or a PHP module instead, the web server module can maintain some state, like database connections for example, across invocations.